# Fill a 2D ArrayList with zeros

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I know I can fill a normal vetor/list with some `zeros` with the following statement:

```
double[][] list = new double[10][10]; // It will automatically inserts 0's in all positions.
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d))); // Also
```

I want to make the same thing **BUT** using a 2D list, is it possible?

```
List<List<Double>> list2 = new ArrayList();
// It doesn't work -> List<List<Double>> list2 = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d)));
```

By the way, I want to avoid to use explicit loop.

Comment: `Collections.nCopies()` will return a list that contains _one_ element in n indices. Since `Double` is immutable this is fine but don't use that with mutable objects such as lists. Btw, the inner array list is not needed. Even the outer list will just be a copy and contain 10 references to the _same_ `Double` instance.

Comment: Also: `I want to avoid to use explicit loop` - why?

Comment: @Thomas because loops are soooo 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following?

```
Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0.0)))
      .limit(10)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It generates an `ArrayList` of type `Collections$CopiesList`.

Answer (score 6):

```
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d)));
```

This is redundant. You pass the list to a secound constructor. This is enough:

```
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d));
```

With a 2D List you can do it like this:

```
List<List<Double>> list2 = new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d))));
```

But be carefull, the list contains ten times the reference to the same list.

If you want to have different lists and avoid and explicit for loop, you can use an implicit for loop and java 8.

```
List<List<Double>> list2 = new ArrayList();
Collections.nCopies(10, new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d))).forEach((list) -> list2.add(new ArrayList(list)));
```

Comment: there is a good chance the use cases will require the lists to be different

Comment: Yes, I saw I copied and pasted it: `List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d)));` wrong, but I did right here in my machine. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

Stream, for example:

```
List<List<Double>> list2 = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0d)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It will also iterate, but implicitly.